# Angular 2, access select value from a button outside the loop

Tags: angular

Notice this code: (click)="deleteDescriptor(descriptor.DescriptorId, #fc+i)

All of the selects get built dynamically. So I'm trying to access the value of the select when they click the delete button, right next to that particular select. Make sense?

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let descriptor of descriptors; let i = index">

                    <label for="descriptor_{{descriptor.DescriptorId}}">{{descriptor.Display}}</label>
                    <span *ngIf="descriptor.IsEditable">
                        <button type="button" class="smAddBtn" (click)="openModal(descriptor.DescriptorId, descriptor.Name)">Add</button>
                        | <button type="button" class="smAddBtn" (click)="deleteDescriptor(descriptor.DescriptorId, #fc+i)">Delete</button>
                    </span>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="descriptor.IsMultiple == true">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="descriptor_{{descriptor.DescriptorId}}" [formControlName]="descriptor.Name" #fc+i>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option *ngFor="let item of descriptor.Items" [value]="item.DescriptorId">{{item.Name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: can't you pass the value in deleteDescriptor function as paramter as you are sending descriptor.DescriptorId?

Comment: no because the btn is outside the look for item.DescriptorId

Comment: Hi Mark! Please take note that you don't have to have a check to test for a variable's truthiness (as seen in `*ngIf="descriptor.IsMultiple == true`). That check should already work in the built-in `ngIf` directive.

Comment: @Edric, I'm aware, but I have bigger issues. Thus the question. Thanks though

Comment: can we get some TypeScript ? what's in deleteDescriptor() ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if at the end you want to delete the selected value in the `Select`, but here's what i got for you :

First you will have to change the id for the `Select` to make sure that it is unique in page. Because right now you will probably have a conflict with the `Label` and the `Select`.

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="selector_descriptor_{{descriptor.DescriptorId}}"[formControlName]="descriptor.Name" #fc+i>
```

And in my TypeScript component, i got :

```
deleteDescriptor(id, dunno) {
    let select: HTMLSelectElement = <HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById(`select_descriptor_${id}`);
    select.remove(select.selectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of the formControl rather than the template reference.

```
<button type="button" class="smAddBtn" (click)="deleteDescriptor(descriptor.DescriptorId, yourForm.get(descriptor.Name).value)">Delete</button>
```